# triggering DataChangedHandler for specific changes

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am trying to create a windows store  app which will store tile settings in roaming settings and a separate file in roaming folder.Now for synchronization purpose i have registered DataChangedHandler for DataChanged event as follows:

```
 public class TileSettings
{

    public TileSettings(Tile tile)
    {
        this.Tile = tile;
        ApplicationData.Current.DataChanged += new TypedEventHandler<ApplicationData, object>(DataChangedHandler); 
    }

    public void DataChangedHandler(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData appData, object o)
    {

        //this.LoadSettings();
    }
}
```

The problem is that this event will be triggered for all the tiles even when the settings for only tile changes or the file in the roaming folder changes. How do I register the event so that it is triggered only for that one tile(whose settings change) or the file(when its content changes)?